# нужна помощь с регулярными выражениями js

Tags: javascript, регулярные-выражения, математика

Мне надо оборачивать выражения рядом с которыми стоит восклицательный знак в функцию факториал.

Например:

```
5! -> factorial(5)
```

Но при этом:

```
5!! -> factorial( factorial(5) )
```

Вообще выражение может быть любой сложности, например:

```
5 + 3 - ((44 - 38)! - 3)!
```

Я долго думал как реализовать это с помощью регулярный выражений, и не смог. Но не обязательно использовать регулярные выражения. Если есть идеи, как реализовать это без регулярок, можете писать.

Comment: Это очень плохая идея пытаться распарсить грамматику регулярками. Очень плохая. Не нужно этого делать. А не регулярными это стандартная задача разбора грамматики

Comment: Формально математически !! — это не факториал факториала, а [двойной факториал](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A4%D0%B0%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B0%D0%BB#%D0%94%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B9%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B9_%D1%84%D0%B0%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B0%D0%BB)..

Comment: Для этого придётся распарсить всё выражение: числа, скобки, все математические знаки. И уже после этого выполнять подмену - после проведённых операций это сложности представлять не будет.

Comment: @Harry добавлю, что для двойного факториала может использоваться отдельный символ ‼ это нужно учесть при парсинге строки.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В целом, я поддерживаю комментарии под вопросом, что это `задача разбора грамматики`. Но так как в вопросе есть пункт: ***Если есть идеи, как реализовать это без регулярок, можете писать.***, напишу вариант как это можно сделать относительно просто, если не предполагаются выражения больше `n!!`

Принцип алгоритма:

- пройти с конца по строке, найти ее диапазоны к которым применяется факториалы.
  например [[8,24], [9, 18], ...] где 8 - начало выражения, 24 - конец перед символом`!`
- далее для безболезненной вставки (чтобы не потерять диапазоны) строка бьется на буквы (массив), теперь вставки не будут влиять на данные о диапазонах.
- делаются вставки с помощью `splice` для каждого диапазона
- массив объединяется в строку - выводится результат

```js
function getStart(s, index){
   let brackets = 0
   for(let i=index-1; i >= 0; i--){
      if (s[i] === ')') brackets++
      if (brackets && s[i] === '(') brackets--
      // возвращаем позицию открывающей скобки
      if (brackets === 0 && s[i] !== '!' ) return i  
   }
}

function replaceFactorial(s, ranges){
   if (ranges.length === 0) return s
   let range = null
   let result = s.split('')
   while(range = ranges.shift()){
      if (s[range[1]-1] === ')'){ // были скобки
         result.splice(range[0] , 1, 'factorial(')
         result.splice(range[1], 1 )
      } else if (s[range[1]+1] === '!'){  // двойной факториал
         result.splice(range[0] , 0, 'factorial(')
         result.splice(range[1] + 2, 1 , ')' )
      } else { // выражение было без скобок, например: 5!!
         result.splice(range[0] , 0, 'factorial(')
         result.splice(range[1] + 1, 1, ')' )
      }
   }
   return result.join('')
}

function transform(s){
   let ranges = []
   for(let i=s.length-1; i >= 0; i--){
      if(s[i] === '!'){
         ranges.push([getStart(s, i), i])
      } 
   }
   return replaceFactorial(s, ranges)
}

let test ='5! + 3 - ((44 - 38)! - 3)! + 7!!' 
console.log(test) 
console.log(transform(test))
```

Comment: Извините за не грамотность спасибо за помощь очень благодарен